# ode45 outputs are all NaN

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve this simple ODE system:

```
dydpdt = 1*(-f{2}-f{1}*dydp);
```

Stored in a function called `funsensitivity` (`f` is a cell array, with a 765x765 sparse matrix and a 765x1 vector, downloadable as a .MAT file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103970417/Cellf.mat) ). I call it using:

```
dydp0 = zeros(size(f{2}));
[t2,JJ]=ode45(@(t,y)funsensitivity(t,y,f),0:4000:100000,dydp0);
```

JJ is the right size, I get no errors, but all values in JJ are `NaN`. I have no idea why this could happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `{}` to index, which is for cell arrays. You should be using `()`:

```
dydpdt = 1*(-f(2)-f(1)*dydp);
```

and also

```
dydp0 = zeros(size(f(2)));
[t2,JJ]=ode45(@(t,y)funsensitivity(t,y,f),0:tstep:tfinal,dydp0);
```

**EDIT based on comments**:

I have tried running your code in Octave (don't have MATLAB), and it looks like your problem is unstable by looking at the solution:

```
JJ =

 Columns 1 through 10:

   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000   0.0000e+000
   5.1645e+001   1.0181e+004   1.2727e+003  -1.1492e+004  -1.2900e+001  -7.2862e+001   7.2502e+001   7.7228e-003   1.1269e-002   1.4324e-003
   1.5631e+031   1.3173e+033   1.6466e+032  -1.4936e+033  -3.7860e+030  -2.2204e+031   2.2012e+031   7.4674e+026   1.0897e+027   1.3851e+026
   7.0857e+060   3.7159e+062   4.6449e+061  -4.2334e+062  -1.6685e+060  -1.0125e+061   1.0005e+061   1.9564e+056   2.8548e+056   3.6287e+055
   3.4854e+090   1.3800e+092   1.7250e+091  -1.5787e+092  -7.9162e+089  -5.0174e+090   4.9378e+090   7.0373e+085   1.0269e+086   1.3053e+085
  -5.3460e+120   5.8857e+121   7.3572e+120  -6.2253e+121   1.3755e+120   7.4917e+120  -7.4825e+120   3.1352e+115   4.5748e+115   5.8151e+114
  -2.3670e+152   2.7260e+151   3.4075e+150   1.4565e+152   5.7833e+151   3.3559e+152  -3.3303e+152   9.3359e+145   1.3623e+146   1.7316e+145
  -7.6120e+183   1.3332e+181   1.6682e+180   5.6622e+183   1.8358e+183   1.0823e+184  -1.0724e+184   3.3770e+177   4.9277e+177   6.2636e+176
  -2.4360e+215   6.7970e+210   9.2304e+209   1.8189e+215   5.8022e+214   3.4726e+215  -3.4359e+215   1.4223e+209   2.0755e+209   2.6381e+208
  -7.7953e+246   4.4692e+240   3.6568e+240   5.8278e+246   1.8337e+246   1.1142e+247  -1.1008e+247   6.0021e+240   8.7582e+240   1.1133e+240
  -2.4947e+278   4.0992e+271   1.3587e+272   1.8673e+278   5.7955e+277   3.5749e+278  -3.5270e+278   2.5328e+272   3.6959e+272   4.6979e+271
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

You might want to try a stiff solver such as `ode15s` to see if it improves things, or using a smaller time step in your time vector, but it looks like the problem is fundamentally wrong (numerically at least).

Comment: f is a cell array, I should have specified it.

Comment: Can you tell us what `f{1}`, `f{2}`, `tstep` and `tfinal` are so that we can attempt to reproduce the issue?

Comment: f{1} is a 765x765 sparse matrix and f{2} is a 765x1 vector. How should I give them to you?

Comment: Oh... I thought they were scalars... Can you maybe upload them to a filesharing site and post a link?

Comment: `.MAT` file in Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103970417/Cellf.mat.
Thank you for your patience!

Comment: The solution is going to infinity, the problem is fundamentally unstable (I think), it's nothing to do with the software.

Comment: Since this is inside a `lsqnonlin` function, with `ode15s` it runs a couple of times then gives me the warning "unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below...". I will ask my colleague who suggested using this method, but at least  this gave me a direction to work towards. Thank you so much for your help!